# Diagnosing and Troubleshooting keyboard shorcut issues

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, super-key

I am currently having trouble setting up some keyboard shortcuts, specifically  the 'super' key.

I am using Linux Mint Mate 18.2 and when used on its own the super key opens my menu bar. Here I can search for apps, shutdown, etc. However I wish to use my super key for other shortcuts but none seem to work. Two instances are:

1) For making guake terminal visible / invisible

and

2) For opening my home folder

In the first case I tried setting the shortcut from the guake terminal preferences but didn't work. In the second case I tried setting it from the Keyboard settings > Shortcuts and also nothing. There are  more scenarios where I would like to use the 'super' key as a shortcut but I'm thinking that if I can get these two to work, the rest would be similar.

How can I go about troubleshooting this problem to identify what is happening and what I would need to do to solve it?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What does 16.04 in the question title mean?

Comment: @weijun I reworded the title of the question to be more generic and avoid confusion with the 16.04 in the title.